# number in a given range if loop python

Tags: python, if-statement

I'm trying to compute this simple expression in python:

if a number is bigger than -1.0 and smaller than 1.0 do something.

I tried this:

```
if x > '-1.0' and x < '1.0':
    DoSomething
```

but it turns out that it evaluates only the second part (x < '1.0').
I also tried

```
if '-1.0' < x < '1.0':
    DoSomething
```

but strangely I don't get what I want. Any suggestion please????

Comment: What output are you getting?  Have you tried removing the quote marks?

Comment: Nothing at all. It should write a line if that is satisfied, anyway I tried removing the quotes but it doesn't help

Comment: What is the value of `x`? Is it also a string? If so you can convert it to a floating point value with `float(x)`. So your if statement would be: `if -1.0 < float(x) < 1.0:`.

Comment: There we go! Thanks srgerg, just needed to specify x as a float.

Answer (score 8):

You are comparing with strings, not numbers.

```
if x > -1.0 and x < 1.0:
    pass
```

Will do the comparison on numbers.

Comment: It's not working....actually at least the strings are doing something, with only the numbers I don't get any error but it doesn't do anything either.

Comment: @eikonal: what type is `x`? Is it a string or a number? You may need to convert `x` to a float first (`float(x)`) before you can do numeric comparisons with it.

Answer (score 2):

You don't want to put the numbers in quotes - that results in a string comparison, not a numeric comparison. You want

```
if x > -1.0 and x < 1.0:
    DoSomething
```

Answer (score 2):

As other answers have mentioned, you need to remove the quotes so that you are comparing with numbers rather than strings.

However, none of those answers used Python's [chained comparisons](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#notin):

```
if -1.0 < x < 1.0:
    DoSomething
```

This is equivalent to `if x > -1.0 and x < 1.0`, but more efficient because `x` is only evaluated once.

Comment: I tried that but it looks like is not evaluating at all. I mean I don't get any error but any result either... x is in the simple format 0.1 or -0.3 and so on in a range between +/- 3

Comment: Try `if -1.0 < float(x) < 1.0`.

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing in that code is comparing x with the string value '-1.0' or '1.0', not the double value. Try the following:

```
if x > -1.0 and x < 1.0:
```

Answer (score 1):

This will also work:

```
if abs(x) < 1.0
```